# canvas keep the first text draw?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I am writing a little app using canvas.

In app have a button "next" when i click next canvas draw another text.

I use clearRect to clear canvas before redraw text. But the first text draw never remove.

This is my code:

```
ctx = $("canvas").get("0").getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = 300;
    ctx.canvas.height = 100;
 var fontSize = 300/4;
    ctx.font= fontSize + "px Times New Roman";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    ctx.fillText(VietBasic.mainWord[0],300/2,(100 - fontSize*1.4)/2);
$("#next").bind("click.next", function(){
       k++;
       if(k >= VietBasic.mainWord.length){
           k=0;
       }
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
       ctx.font= fontSize + "px Times New Roman";
       ctx.textAlign = 'center';
       ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
       ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
       ctx.fillText(VietBasic.mainWord[k],300/2,(100 - fontSize*1.4)/2);
       $("#imgSample").html(VietBasic.mainWord[k]);

       $("#wordSample").html(VietBasic.keyWord[k]);

       $("#mainImg").attr("src",VietBasic.imageSample[k]);
    });
```

This is screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Please help me, i am newbie...
Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Probably a bug in the Android environment. There have been problems with clearRect in the past. See if not this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804710/android-4-html5-canvas-not-redrawing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with your clearRect call. Your having it use your ctx.canvas.height value, but thats only set to 100, and your canvas is much bigger than that.

```
ctx.canvas.width = 300;
ctx.canvas.height = 100;
...
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
```

you going to want to use something like

```
var myCanvas= document.getElementById("myCanvasID");

ctx.clearRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
```

or at least for the time being set

```
ctx.canvas.height = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i try your way! but still have same error. Have any idea??

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to see whats going on if you change the       ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); to a ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); and see where this coordinates are... give it a fill style that will stand out ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)";

Comment: I already try it, it work to hide first text draw, but as you see in the image, i use background, so i dont want fill canvas because it's hide my background

Comment: Yeah I get that, I just wanted to verify that the rect used for clearRect was where you expected it to be, and it sounds like fillRect confirms it is. At this point, you should try some of the other methods to clear the canvas... $("canvas").get("0").width=100; $("canvas").get("0").width=ctx.canvas.width; this will force it to reset the canvas ctx.